# Azure slot swapping cause HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.2

I've got an simple asp.net core 2.2 API. It is configured to deploy to azure as soon as we check-in into the master branch.

Azure devops release pipeline is configured to deploy it to an staging slot first. Then it does an smoke web test (by going to one end-point) and if that is successful then it swap the slot with production.

When the slot is swaped it does the same smoke web test (by going to the same end-point on production) to check if it still works. A lot of times i then get an HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure.

Deploying the same build again fixes this problem most of the times. But i cannot find any logs or details why this error occurds and how to fix this.

Any idea how to debug an HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure on a Azure Web App?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out Azure has an internally known (I guess they are not eager to share the news about this) problem with 'Application Insights'.

So turn that feature off (if it's on), and see if it solves the issue. That step solved the problem for me.

Comment: 7 December 2019 this issue still exists and your answer helped me. The application was using ASP.NET Core 3.0. In case you turn off Application Insights from portal's blade, keep in mind that you also have to remove some configuration settings under Configuration blade.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with an Azure ASP.Net Core 2.2 that was running fine for several weeks and suddenly started generating this error from Oct 15 to Oct 17.

Microsoft tech support folks tried to help for a couple of days but they couldn't figure out why the stdout logs were blank. Then, after 2 days, it turned out that it was a known problem on Microsoft's side and they promised to fix. Indeed, after about 8 hours the application started working again (no change or redeployment of the application on my side!).

I asked for an explanation but they told me it was too sensitive.

Today, after 2 weeks of working well, the same application is back to showing the same exact error: "HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure"

So, most likely, the problem is not in your code or deployment procedure. Instead, the problem is Azure (perhaps how they provision the .net core 2.2 runtime). But for some odd reason Microsoft is not willing to share the details of the problem with their user community (or permanently solve it). Very disappointing!